# Code Igniter Welcome Page Does Not Appear (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just added Code Igniter to my XAMPP directory. When I open up this URL, I can see the Welcome screen:

```
http://localhost:1372/codeigniter/index.php/welcome
```

Now I want to remove the `index.php` part of this URL.

So on `config.php` in `application/config`, I did set the

`$config['base_url']` to `'http://localhost:1372/codeigniter/';`

and

`$config['index_page']` to `'';` .

Then I created an `.htaccess` page on the root directory and added these codes to it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index/.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

So what now should happen is to see the default Welcome page on `http://localhost:1372/codeigniter/` URL. But instead of that I get the **Internal Server Error** somehow!

So what is my mistake. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the codes of htaccess and save it, then refresh the page, see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable mod_rewrite extension.
open the file:

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

find the line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and uncoment it (remove the # symbol). thus this line must be look like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

then search all lines with:

```
AllowOverride None
```

and change them to

```
AllowOverride All
```

then save the file and restart XAMPP